# What is std::thread::hardware_concurrency returns?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I was experimenting with my mach laptop while reading [C++ Concurrency in Action](https://www.amazon.co.uk/C-Concurrency-Action-Practical-Multithreading/dp/1933988770), one of the ver first examples is to identify the number of the actual hw threads with `std::thread::hardware_concurrency()`, which returns 8 on my machine.
But before printing `std::thread::hardware_concurrency()`I have made a type and printed`std::thread::hardware_concurrency` which was `00B61410`.

So what is the difference between `std::thread::hardware_concurrency() and std::thread::hardware_concurrency`? What does the later identify?

Comment: How did you print `std::thread::hardware_concurrency`?  `std::thread::hardware_concurrency` is a function so only it's return value is meaningful.

Comment: std::cout << std::thread::hardware_concurrency << std::endl; and it gives 00B61410

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`std::thread::hardware_concurrency()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/hardware_concurrency) is a static member function of `std::thread` which

> Returns the number of concurrent threads supported by the implementation. The value should be considered only a hint.

So the `8` you get is your "max conncurent threads".

When you do

```
std::cout << std::thread::hardware_concurrency << std::endl;
```

you are printing the address of the function.  The value that you get is basically meaningless unless you want to pass that function pointer to something else.